# Different prices for products

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog-price-rules, vat

There is a different price in the catalog en the product.
In the catalog the product cost 21.48 euro and when i go to the product then the price is 23.21 euro.
The difference is not in the VAT, that is 25.99 euro incl.
Where does the difference in price from.

Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

The price difference is 8.05% between 21.48 and 23.21.  21.48 * 0.0805 = 1.73 + 21.48 = 23.21

According to this, you are calculating VAT at 21%.  21.48 * 0.21 = 4.51 + 21.48 = 25.99

You should look in your `Admin -> Promotions -> Catalog Price Rules` to see if you have an Active rule for approximately 8% discount.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. But there is no Catalog price rule there. Catalog price rules is empty.

Comment: I have look in the price rules, there are no rules available. I have several items checked for any 8% rules, but did not find anything.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question, but have you reindexed and flushed cache?